# Appending map that uses Struct as a "multikey" and std::vector as mapped value

Tags: c++, vector, key, stdmap, multikey

in code below it appends `myList` only for the first call of `appendMyList()`, and size stays 1, so can someone explain what is wrong here:

```
struct MyKey {
  int accValue;
  std::string name;
};

inline bool operator<(MyKey a, MyKey b){
  return a.accValue < b.accValue && a.name < b.name;
}

inline bool operator==(MyKey a, MyKey b){
  return a.accValue == b.accValue && a.name == b.name;
}

typedef std::map<MyKey, std::vector<int>> MyList;

class MyClass {
    public:
    void appendMyList(int accVal, std::string name, int element) {
        myList[MyKey{accVal, name}].push_back(element);
        cout<<endl<<"Size after"<< myList.size()<<endl;
    }

   MyList myList;
};
```

I saw similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736803/stdmap-with-struct-as-key) but don't see anything wrong with my operators, so I guess it's something else?

This is how i call the function:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass imHere;
    int a = 1;
    std::string yaya = "name";
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            imHere.appendMyList((++a), yaya, i);
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: `return (a.accValue < b.accValue) || (a.accValue == b.accValue && a.name < b.name);`

Comment: @cigien i edited
PiotrSkotnicki hmm, not sure what are you trying to say?

Comment: That's how your `operator<` should look like. Alternatively, `return std::tie(a.accValue, a.name) < std::tie(b.accValue, b.name);`

Comment: When the `name`s are the same, your `operator<` will return false even if `accValue`s are different. So your map never inserts anything else.

Comment: Thanks for help, == operator can stay the same right?

Comment: Yes, though `std::map` doesn't use it.

Comment: @Bodega if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` then map considers `a` and `b` equivalent, hence no more elements than one are inserted. your `operator<` is wrong as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::map` does not allow for storing duplicates. However, it doesn't use `operator==` for checking *equality* of elements. It uses `operator<` for both -- ordering elements as well as checking *equivalence*.

That is, if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` then `std::map` considers `a` and `b` equivalent, hence no more elements than one are inserted using your `operator<`, because `name` is the same in all elements, thus both `(a < b)` and `(b < a)` return `false`.

Instead, you should be using:

```
inline bool operator<(MyKey a, MyKey b) {
  return a.accValue < b.accValue || (a.accValue == b.accValue && a.name < b.name);
}
```

or:

```
inline bool operator<(MyKey a, MyKey b) {
  return std::tie(a.accValue, a.name) < std::tie(b.accValue, b.name);
}
```